# Pointer Cast in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, strict-aliasing

I have the following three `struct`s.

```
struct A {
  int a;
  int bOffset;
  int cOffset;
};

struct B {
  long long b;
  int other[];
};

struct C {
  long long c;
  int other[];
};
```

The `main` function is like:

```
int main(void) {
  int otherSize = 0;
  scanf("%d", &otherSize);

  int aSize = sizeof(struct A);
  int bSize = sizeof(struct B) + sizeof(int) * otherSize;
  int cSize = sizeof(struct C) + sizeof(int) * otherSize;
  int totalSize = aSize + bSize + cSize;

  struct A *a = malloc(totalSize);
  a->bOffset = aSize;
  a->cOffset = aSize + bSize;

  struct B *b = (struct B*)((char*)a + a->bOffset);
  struct C *c = (struct C*)((char*)a + a->cOffset);

  ......
}
```

The space of `struct A`, `struct B` and `struct C` is allocated together to show better cache behavior. My question is, according to previous posts on SO, the cast

```
  struct B *b = (struct B*)((char*)a + a->bOffset);
  struct C *c = (struct C*)((char*)a + a->cOffset);
```

is an undefined behavior in C because `struct B` and `struct C` have stricter alignment requirement than `struct A`. **Then what can I do so that the cast is well-defined in C?**

What I can come up with now is to add a `long long` variable to `struct A` as follow.

```
struct A {
  int a;
  int bOffset;
  int cOffset;
  long long unused;
};
```

**Another question is if I dereference `b` or `c`, it is also an UB. Is there any way to address this issue?**

Comment: I would probably give up the idea of having two flexible array members inside the same chunk of memory, because it gives too many unknown variables. What you win in cache coherence you lose in complexity. Maybe treat it all as one big array of int and memcpy from that array to temporary variables for those few cases where you need long long etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Then what can I do so that the cast is well-defined in C?

To calculate correctly where `struct B` and `struct C` should be placed, you should pad the previous sizes to the necessary alignment. C provides the `_Alignof` operator to provide the alignment requirement of a type. So this code will do the job:

```
/*  Calculate how many bytes are required to add to size s to make it be a
    multiple of alignment a.  If s is a multiple of a, this is zero.
    Otherwise, we need to add a-r bytes, where r is the remainder of s divided
    by a.

    Omitting the parentheses used for macro parameters, the following code is
    a - (s-1)%a - 1.  To see it works, consider two cases:


        s is a multiple of a.  Then s-1 is a-1 modulo a, and the expression
        evaluates to a - (a-1) - 1 = 0.

        s has some non-zero remainder r modulo a.  Then (s-1)%a evaluates to
        r-1, and the expression evaluates to a - (r-1) - 1 = a-r.
*/
#define PadToAlignment(s, a)    ((a) - ((s)-1) % (a) - 1)

…

    //  Add padding needed to align struct B and struct C correctly.
    aSize += PadToAlignment(aSize,         _Alignof (struct B));
    bSize += PadToAlignment(aSize + bSize, _Alignof (struct C));
```

### Notes

You should generally use `size_t` rather than `int` for sizes. Also, when using types with `sizeof` and `_Alignof`, I prefer not to write them like function calls, as in `sizeof(int)`, because they are not function calls. Rather, they are operators with an operand that is a typename enclosed in parentheses for grammatical reasons, so `sizeof (int)` helps remind readers of the meaning of the C code.

Here is complete program incorporating these:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*  Calculate how many bytes are required to add to size s to make it be a
    multiple of alignment a.  If s is a multiple of a, this is zero.
    Otherwise, we need to add a-r bytes, where r is the remainder of s divided
    by a.

    Omitting the parentheses used for macro parameters, the following code is
    a - (s-1)%a - 1.  To see it works, consider two cases:


        s is a multiple of a.  Then s-1 is a-1 modulo a, and the expression
        evaluates to a - (a-1) - 1 = 0.

        s has some non-zero remainder r modulo a.  Then (s-1)%a evaluates to
        r-1, and the expression evaluates to a - (r-1) - 1 = a-r.
*/
#define PadToAlignment(s, a)    ((a) - ((s)-1) % (a) - 1)


struct A {
  int a;
  int bOffset;
  int cOffset;
};

struct B {
  long long b;
  int other[];
};

struct C {
  long long c;
  int other[];
};


int main(void)
{
    int otherSize = 0;
    if (1 != scanf("%d", &otherSize))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, scanf failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t aSize = sizeof (struct A);
    size_t bSize = sizeof (struct B) + sizeof (int) * otherSize;
    size_t cSize = sizeof (struct C) + sizeof (int) * otherSize;

    //  Add padding needed to align struct B and struct C correctly.
    aSize += PadToAlignment(aSize,         _Alignof (struct B));
    bSize += PadToAlignment(aSize + bSize, _Alignof (struct C));

    size_t totalSize = aSize + bSize + cSize;

    unsigned char *RawMemory = malloc(totalSize);
    if (!RawMemory)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct A *a = (struct A *) RawMemory;
    a->bOffset = aSize;
    a->cOffset = aSize + bSize;

    struct B *b = (struct B *) (RawMemory + a->bOffset);
    struct C *c = (struct C *) (RawMemory + a->cOffset);

    printf("a is at %p.\n", (void *) a);
    printf("b is at %p.\n", (void *) b);
    printf("c is at %p.\n", (void *) c);

    free(RawMemory);
}
```

### Another question is if I dereference b or c, it is also an UB.

Memory allocated by `malloc` has no effective type. It may be used as any type by storing data there through an lvalue of that type.

The C standard’s rules about effective types in dynamically allocated memory involving structures are incomplete; the natural language wording is insufficient to write a formal semantic description. Certainly it is clear that if a `struct S` has members `a`, `b`, and `c` and no others, and we do:

```
struct S *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
p->a = 3;
p->b = 4;
p->c = 5;
```

then, for aliasing considerations, there should be a `struct S` at the memory address `p` even though the memory has only been written in parts, never with a full `struct S` lvalue. But the standard’s rules about effective type do not make this clear; they are are simply inadequate.

Putting multiple structures in the memory further complicates this. However, the purpose of the standard’s aliasing rules is to specify when objects can or cannot be aliased (and hence what optimizations the compiler can do regarding these). For practical purposes, as long as you use these structures in normal ways (the memory you designate for `struct A` as a `struct A`, the memory you designate for `struct B` as a `struct B`, and the memory you designate for `struct C` as a `struct C`), then you are not aliasing the memory with other types, and compilers are not going to perform unexpected optimizations that break that. I expect it is safe to use the allocated memory in this way.

Comment: If one were to give Committee members a survey with constructs that test various corner cases and ask whether they should be processed in a manner consistent with processing loads and stores as reads and writes of bit patterns from untyped storage, there would almost certainly be many constructs for which there was neither a consensus saying all implementations should be required to support them, nor that all programs should be required to avoid them at all cost.  The only way for the Standard to say anything useful would be to say that many implementations should be expected to handle...

Comment: ...corner cases that may not be supportable on all, but historically the Standard avoided saying anything about constructs that wouldn't be universally mandated, and seems unwilling to change parts of the Standard that have "worked" for 30 years, even if the only reason they "worked" is that implementations would meaningfully process some constructs for which the Standard imposed no requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Much of the Standard was written before type-based aliasing was a consideration, and use terminology which is inadequate to unambiguously specify what is or is not defined in any reasonable fashion (any consistent reading would either classify as undefined constructs which should obviously work, or define constructs which clang nor gcc refuse to support except when type-based aliasing is disabled).

For example, given the definitions:

```
struct s1 { int dat[4]; } *x1;
struct s2 { int dat[4]; } *x2;
int i;
```

the Standard explicitly states that the lvalues `x1->dat[i]` and `*(x1->dat+i)` are equivalent (in fact, the former is *defined* as meaning the latter), and it would be absurd to suggest that a function which expects an `int*` shouldn't be able to use it to access the object at either `x1->dat+i` or `x2->dat+i` interchangeably, but neither gcc nor clang will reliably recognize that the lvalue expressions `x1->dat[i]` might access an object of type `struct s2`.

If the Standard had specified that arrays do not decay when used with the `[]` operator, but instead defined the behavior of the `[]` operator on array-type members of structs or unions as being an access to part of the containing struct or union, that would make it possible to resolve a lot of ambiguities in the Standard, but instead the Standard treats all such constructs as Undefined Behavior and relies upon implementations to exercise judgment as to which should be supported and which not.